# A problem regarding $\sin(4x) = \sin(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

Given trigonometric equation

$$\sin(4x) = \sin(2x)$$

I'm trying to obtain $x$.

**Case I)**

$$\sin(\pi - 4x) = \sin(2x)$$

$$\pi - 4x = 2x$$

$$\boxed {\dfrac{\pi}{6} =  x}$$

**Case II)**

$$\sin(2\pi - 4x) = \sin(2x)$$

$$2\pi - 4x = 2x$$

$$\boxed {\dfrac{\pi}{3} =  x}$$

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: $\sin(\theta) = \sin \phi \implies \theta = \phi + 2 n \pi, n = 0, \pm 1, ...$

Comment: What is your assumption? What about $x=0?$ Remember that the functions are periodic, i.e. there are countable solutions.

Comment: case II is peculiar. I would switch it for case 0: $4x=2x$. Further: what is the domain of $x$ here?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to use the fact that $\sin(4x)= \sin(2\cdot 2x) = 2\sin(2x)\cos(2x),$ so that $\sin(4x) = \sin(2x) \Leftrightarrow \sin(2x) \left(2\cos(2x) - 1\right) = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! $60^{\circ}$ is not a root.

Also,  you equation has infinitely many solutions.
$$4x=2x+360^{\circ}k,$$ where $k$ is an integer number, which is
$$x=180^{\circ}k$$ or
$$4x=180^{\circ}-2x+360^{\circ}k,$$ which gives
$$x=30^{\circ}+60^{\circ}k$$ and we got the answer:
$$\left\{180^{\circ}k,30^{\circ}+60^{\circ}k|k\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$

Comment: Why using degrees (I dislike them) if in the question radials are used?

Comment: @Vera I just like degrees. Here it's the same.  If you want you can fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and giving me the liberty.  I choose to respect your likes and will not fix.

Answer (score 1):

Change the form of $\sin(4x)=\sin(2x)$ to get $2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)=\sin(2x)$

If $\sin(2x)=0$, $2x=n \pi$ and $x=\frac{n \pi}{2}.$ Where $n$ is an integer.
If $\sin(2x) \neq 0,$ $\cos(2x)=\frac{1}{2}$ $\space$ $2x=2m\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{3}$ $\space$ $x=m\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{6}.$
Where $m$ is an integer.

$x=\frac{n\pi}{2},m\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{6}$

Answer (score 0):

Your second case is clearly not true, for if $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$

$\sin(4x)=-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

and

$\sin(2x)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

so this counter-example disproves your conjecture ... for all you actually asked was **"Is my assumption correct?"**